# why don't inline events with function names work on divs?

Tags: javascript, html, events, inline, inline-code

I feel like this is such a noob question but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/37pj3bro/5/

```
<div onclick="dingo()">click me</div>
<div onclick="alert(this)">click me 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dingo()
{
    alert("hi");
}
</script>
```

The first click me does not alert but the second one does. I can't figure out why....

Comment: working after putting script in head tag http://jsfiddle.net/37pj3bro/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question works fine:

```html
<div onclick="dingo()">click me</div>
<div onclick="alert(this)">click me 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dingo()
{
    alert("hi");
}
</script>
```

The code in JS fiddle doesn't work because you've configured it so `dingo` is not a global.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @SvenB — Because if you select ondomready then you assign the anonymous function to domready instead of onload … but `dingo`  is still defined inside another function so it is still not a global so it is still out of scope.

Comment: Then why doesn't this work: http://jsfiddle.net/37pj3bro/9/. `mango` is defined in the head and added at run-time later with .onclick = "mango()"; I know I can do `.onclick = mango` but why can't I give it as a string?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  — Because the value of the property is required to be a function, not a string.

Comment: @Quentin: Oh. Well that puts a damper on things for me. Understood. Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer, and mine seems to be not right, deleting my answer.